# Reusing assigned labels in rule definition in ANTLR

Tags: antlr3

I have a rule to match 'FOR "hi" FOR'

```
rule : id1=ELEMENT STRING id1
{
   // action
} 
 -> ^(Tree rule)
```

but it fails saying reference to undefined rule: id1
How can I reuse a label to ensure the start and end of the rule are the same identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to handle this is *assume* the values match while parsing, and then examine the AST after parsing is complete, issuing error messages at that time for any mismatched elements.

This approach results in a more robust parser and much much understandable error messages in the case of an wrote.